# Allow only classes in predefined packages to call a constructor/method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a class and I want only some class to be allowed to call its constructor.
I know that, by plain java, the only way to attain this is to make constructor at package level and/or make it protected but isn't there some framework/library allowing me to do something like this:

```
@AllowedCallers({"com.foo", "foo.bar"})
public MyConstructor(){
   ....
}
```

?

Comment: Use java modules, and don't export the package this class is in.

Comment: I'm on java 8 unfortunately so no modules :(

Answer (score 0):

This could be a way;

1. make all of the class constructors as private
2. add a static method and restrict the caller by generic bound `public static <T extends ClassCanCallNew> void newMyClass(T clazz, Object... args)`
3. Only someone extends the ClassCanCallNew can call the private constructors with this method
4. `clazz.setMyClass(new MyClass(args));` make this line suits your own need